# Community Wiki for ChromiumOS on "such and such" device

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I've started dabbling in installing ChromiumOS on various machines and would like to contribute my progress somewhere. Should I create a new wiki page per device or start with a master one that would be empty for sometime? As it's definitely an emerging but still low volume Q&A demand, perhaps it's better to just put some specific questions and answer them myself, such as "X won't display for MacBook 2007 in ChromiumOS"?

I don't wish to maintain my own blog and enjoy the usability of SE only about 1,000 times more than Google Groups (one of the current tomes of ChromiumOS Q&A).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely post your own questions and answers. Not sure what you mean by 'wiki', the only 'wikis' here would be the tags and that is *not* what they're for.

The ['community wiki'](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) is not that clearly defined anymore and is usually used when someone does not want to take credit for other people's work. Posting and answering your own question is both accepted and [encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), if someone feels they need to edit, they can, I see no reason for you to mark them as wiki directly.

So, posting questions and answers about problems you faced and solved would be great! Please do so.